# Swift Alamofire RequestInterceptor not called if using SessionDelegate

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to refresh my authentication credential for my request using [Alamofire's RequestInterceptor](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests-with-requestinterceptor).

I noticed I am unable to enter the `validate()` portion of the interceptor as my breakpoints show me I am entering my `SessionDelegate` handlers instead. More precisely the [`urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession) and [`urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411610-urlsession) methods of my SessionDelegate class seems to swallow the logic for the `RequestInterceptor`. If I remove these two handlers from my `SessionDelegate` I am able to enter the `validate()` code which then triggers the `refresh` method on my [Authenticator](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#authenticationinterceptor) class.

Is there a way to force the `RequestInteceptor` to intercept my request and refresh my credential if needed before it enters my `SessionDelegate` handlers? Removing the handlers from my `SessionDelegate` is not an option as I need to perform specific business logic in there.

Code:

```
        self.session = Session(delegate: mySessionDelegate, interceptor: myRequestInterceptor)
        self.session.request(myURL)
            .validate({ _, response, data -> DataRequest.ValidationResult in
                let statusCode = response.statusCode
                //this code is not entered if I have my SessionDelegate handler
                if 200 ... 299 ~= statusCode { return .success(Void()) }
                return .failure(AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason: .unacceptableStatusCode(code: statusCode)))
            })
            .resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a custom `SessionDelegate` subclass (which isn't recommended; there's almost always a better way to accomplish what you need), it's your responsibility to call `super` in your overridden methods, as they contain important events. Otherwise you'll break important Alamofire events, as you've found.